# Make a button visible after some time with NSTimer

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nstimer

I'm trying to develop a new application for `iOS` but I'm stuck with `NSTimer` :-(. Currently I have a `void` function which hides an `UIButton` after the user taps twice or more on the screen and a `NSTimer`. I want to make the button visible again after the `NSTimer` reaches 5 seconds and stop and reset it right after in order to re-hide it after the user taps twice again :-) but I don't know how to tell the app that 5 seconds have passed :-/.

Can someone help me, please? :-)

Here's the code so far :-)

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSUInteger numTaps = [[touches anyObject] tapCount];

    if (numTaps >= 2)
    {
        // Other code//

        [self.button setHidden:YES];
        buttonHideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 invocation:nil repeats:NO];

        // Other code //
    }
}
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: David's answer is good. I'd also suggest that you check to see if a timer already exists, and if so, `invalidate` that one before creating a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The timer needs to have a selector, which will tell the timer what to do after the time has passed:

```
buttonHideTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(showButtonNow) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Comment: Thanks David :-D I've wrote the code in the app now and it works!